# What is a more concise way of calculating the offset?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, refactoring

This code:

```
private int GetColumnToPopulate(int columnBase, int offset) {
    int duckbillColNum = 0;
    switch (columnBase) {
        case 0:
            duckbillColNum = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            duckbillColNum = 5;
            break;
        case 2:
            duckbillColNum = 9;
            break;
        case 3:
            duckbillColNum = 13;
            break;
        case 4:
            duckbillColNum = 17;
            break;
        case 5:
            duckbillColNum = 21;
            break;
        case 6:
            duckbillColNum = 25;
            break;
        case 7:
            duckbillColNum = 29;
            break;
    }
    duckbillColNum += offset;
    return duckbillColNum;
}
```

...is easy to grok, but verbose and clunky. I would like to streamline it. My pseudocode idea is something like:

```
int[] colBases
{
    0..7
}
int[] offsets
{
    1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29
}
int idx = colBases.IndexOf(columnBase);
duckbillColNum = offsets[idx];
```

...or perhaps a multidimensional int array? At any rate, the "IndexOf" business, of course, does not comp[ile,ute].

Comment: Get rid of `colBases` and it's all good

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried your either of your ideas?  This doesn't seem like a well researched problem.

Comment: It struck me with `columnBase * 4 + 1`... Of course if it's enough for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
private int GetColumnToPopulate(int columnBase, int offset) {
   return (columnBase * 4) + 1 + offset;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a `Dictionary`, you could define it like this:

```
Dictionary<int, int> offsets = new Dictionary<int, int>()
    {
        { 0, 1 },
        { 1, 5 },
        { 2, 9 },
        { 3, 13 },
        { 4, 17 },
        { 5, 21 },
        { 6, 25 },
        { 7, 29 },
    }
```

And then when using it:

```
return offsets[columnBase];
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you should replace the switch with this expression `duckbillColNum = columnBase*4 +1;` isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a simple mathematical pattern:

```
private int GetColumnToPopulate(int columnBase, int offset) 
{ return 1 + (columnBase * 4) + offset; }
```